# How do I disable Firefox push notifications in Kubuntu?

Tags: firefox, kde, notification

When I download a file in Firefox, KDE pops up a push notification, like this:

[image]

I don't like this notification. I already get plenty of feedback that the download has started from Firefox's animation, and I can monitor the progress of the download while in another window using the taskbar animation. So I went to the system's per-application notification settings to disable it. Except, Firefox isn't listed there.

[image]

How do I disable this particular notification?

Answer (score 2):

The obvious solution is to **simply disable or remove the Plasma Integration addon in Firefox**. Without that, Firefox transfers are not integrated anymore into the Plasma notifications.

---

**In case that integration is needed for some reason:**

What is especially annoying about that pop-up is the fact that it stays open **as long as the transfer**. Thus it even covers the Firefox downloads button etc.

(What we don't want is losing completely all the transfer info by disabling **only** "Show in notifications" (as the initial answer told us to do):  that would disable all progress, including Dolphin transfer which then cannot be monitored - as it takes place in the background, with just the task manager bar but no details and no possible intervention like stopping etc.)

That can be disabled by unchecking just the option "Keep popup open during transfer". After that, the popup will close after a number of seconds that can be reduced. Also, its location on the screen can be changed.

[image]

There is a way of removing Firefox transfers (and all transfers) from notifications without losing all info (popup or window) about that: by re-enabling the old-style normal transfer window as in old KDE and other desktops, by unchecking both task manager and notifications for "application progress"

[image]

Dolphin transfer then:

[image]

But that now includes the Firefox transfer too in a separate window (with Plasma integration addon), something some people may want

[image]

but it is embarrassing that for Firefox this kind of window is lacking the "Pause" button.

(The fact that we have to either disable **only** the "Keep popup during progress"  -- and have the needed info in notifications for a short time that can be changed -- or **both** task manager and notifications which triggers a separate kwin window for transfers, but **not** just notifications is probably buggy, as that separate window should appear in all cases when the transfer is not shown in notifications.)

Answer (score 1):

You can now do this via the Plasma Integration extension's preferences.

[image: Plasma Integration extensions]

Just disable *Show downloads in notification area*

Comment: Best solution in 2023, thank you @DominicCarrington

Answer (score 0):

In System Settings → *Notifications*, under *Application progress*, uncheck the *Show in notifications* checkbox.

[image: System Settings → Notifications]

Comment: No way, that would disable all progress info in the notifications, including Dolphin transfer which then cannot be monitored - as it takes place in the background, with just the task manager bar but no details and no possible intervention like stopping etc

Comment: We have to either disable **only** the "Keep popup during progress" (and have the needed info in notifications for a short time that can be changed), or **both** task manager and notifications (which triggers a separate kwin window for transfers), but **not** just notifications. That is buggy I guess, as that separate window should appear in all cases when the transfer is not shown in notifications.